# Easybase.io 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: reactjs, database, cloud

I'm using Easybase.io as a database for my React app and I'm running into issues with updating and deleting records.
I'm using the easybase-react hook in a functional component to query the database

```
const {db, e} = useEasybase();
```

Everything works perfectly when I run a select query or an insert query:

```
INSERT: db('TEST').insert({number: 16}).one()
SELECT: let record = await db('TEST').where(e.eq('number', 16)).return().one()
        console.log(record) //returns the appropriate record
```

But when I get errors when I try to delete or update the record. This is what I tried from the docs found here https://easybase.github.io/EasyQB/docs/update_queries.html

```
db('TEST').where(e.eq('number', 16)).set({number: 20}).one()
```

This gives the following error:

```
browser-ponyfill.js:518 POST https://api.easybase.io/PROJECT/project-Transblue-######### 502 (Bad Gateway)
```

I've also tried deleting that specific record, and deleting just the first row of the table without the where parameter:

```
db('TEST').where(e.eq('number', 16)).delete().one()
db('TEST').delete().one()
```

Both queries give the same 502 Bad Gateway error.

Signed in users and users not signed in both have full permission to read and write table records

Has anybody encountered this before?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Comment: Yes! I messaged Easybase about it and it turned out to be a bug in their code. They fixed it and everything worked perfectly again